# ActiveMQ createSession timeout

Tags: java, session, connection, activemq-classic

Is there any way of setting a timeout when creating a session Object from a ActiveMQ connection?

The code I'm using looks as follows:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = Settings.getJmsConnectionFactory(ip);
connection = factory.createConnection();
// insert timeout here
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = session.createTopic(Settings.Topic);
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(topic);
consumer.setMessageListener(this);
connection.start();
```

This works fine as long as the message server is already launched. Otherwise the createSession call will block. I could execute it on another thread to avoid the application from blocking, but I thought I'd ask to find out whether there's a "cleaner" way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's on the createSession() call? If the server isn't available, it should fail on createConnection(). If you don't have a server running, and you're using the [failover transport](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html), it'll try to reconnect forever using the default settings. Look at the transport options for the failover transport for how you can fix it.

Comment: I've been using ActiveMQ for a couple of years now and have never encountered something like this. It always fails at createConnection(), or else it connects all the way. Are you doing something in the same JVM as the broker that might make it stall somehow?

Comment: I had the same issue with the failover trying to reconnect forever.  I added transport.startupMaxReconnectAttempts=6 (or whatever # u choose)  as a query string to the end of our active mq service url to prevent the endless loop.  Now it fails appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As lcrepas pointed out in his comment, that should be the correct answer:

Add `transport.startupMaxReconnectAttempts=1` to your connection string.

Also add `transport.maxReconnectAttempts=1`.